# TensorFlow Error on GPU:InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 991232 values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have run a code from this link:
https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/
The code is given below:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    x_train = np.random.random((100, 100, 100, 3))
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 1)), num_classes=10)
    x_test = np.random.random((20, 100, 100, 3))
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 1)), num_classes=10)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=32)
```

When I run this code using CPU as with tf.device('/cpu:0'), the code runs fine completing all the epochs.

Please note my laptop support NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M. 
I have installed tensorflow-gpu version 1.9.0',cuda9.2 along with NVIDIA cuDNN.

When I run the same code with GPU using tf.device('/gpu:0') its breaks even in the first epoch generating error. Any comments are appreciate spent a lot of time but could not sort it out. The error is given below:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 991232 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1048701955


[[Node: flatten_3/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@training_3/SGD/gradients/dropout_10/cond/Merge_grad/cond_grad"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dropout_10/cond/Merge-2-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer, flatten_3/stack)]]
[[Node: loss_3/mul/_283 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_790_loss_3/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Your operating system? windows? linux? maxos?

Comment: I am using window 10.

Comment: If you use `pip` to install,  make sure `cuda9.0` is installed. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20865#issuecomment-405453895

Comment: I downloaded and installed Cuda 9.2 directly from the Cuda, website. then i installed tensorflow-gpu using :

conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu  followed by keras using 

 conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu

does this make any difference,

Comment: I can run the above code without any problem. It's must be an environment issue. It's better you install `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn` through `anaconda` as well.

Comment: thanks , so u mean I should first uninstall the already cudatoolkit and cudnn and then reinstall it with anaconda. in that case what enviornment variable should i need to set.